# Transpose column in Pandas DataFrame to headers

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': [1,2,3], 
                    'val': ['a','b','c'],
                    'val1': ['t','y','u'],
                    'Group': ['Group1','Group2','Group3'],
                    '2017_1': [45,56,78],
                    '2017_2': [87,32,42]
                 })
```

I'd like to transpose the DataFrame, where values in `Group` column are new column headers and columns `2017_1`, `2017_2` are row values.

Expected output:

```
id val val1 Date_Mon Group1 Group2 Group3
1  a   t    2017_1   45     56     78
2  b   y    2017_2   87     32     42
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars =['id','val','val1','Group'],
             var_name = "Date",
             value_name = "Value")
```